# simplify the number theory function

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to simplify the function:
$$\sum_{n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n^{s+1}}=\frac{1}{\phi\left(q^{\prime}\right)} \sum_\chi \bar{\chi}\left(a^{\prime}\right) \sum_{n^{\prime}=1}^{\infty} \chi\left(n^{\prime}\right) \frac{\phi\left(b n^{\prime}\right)-\mu\left(b n^{\prime}\right)}{\left(b n^{\prime}\right)^{s+1}}$$

where $b=(a,q), n'=n/b, a'=a/b, q'=q/b$.
to the function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n^{s+1}} \\
& \quad=\frac{1}{b^{s+1} \phi\left(q^{\prime}\right)} \sum_\chi \frac{\bar{\chi}\left(a^{\prime}\right)(\phi(b) L(s, \chi)-\mu(b))}{L(s+1, \chi) \prod_{p \mid b}\left(1-\chi(p) p^{-s-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

But there is some problem due to the product of $b$ and $n'$. I am confused why the $\prod_{p|b}(1-\chi(p)p_{-s-1})$ because I know how to prove the identity:
$$
\sum_n \frac{\chi(n)(\phi(n)-\mu(n))}{n^{s+1}}=\frac{L(s, \chi)-1}{L(s+1, \chi)}
$$
Do you know how to deal with it? Thank you for advance !

Comment: dealing with $\mu (ab)$ is ok because you can factor it as $\mu(a)\mu (b)$ and keep a condition $(a,b)=1$ in your sum.  for $\phi (ab)$ i'm not sure, but you could try writing $\phi /id=1/id\star \mu $ so that you just have a problem with $\mu $ again.  can write more details if you want, but it's more just an idea to try first

Comment: The problem is that b and n' are not coprime, so for $\mu$ I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: i understand that. but for general $a,b$ you can factor $\mu (ab)$ by putting an $(a,b)=1$ in the sum bc it vanishes when $(a,b)>1$. i'll write it down later if you want

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, just showing how to deal with the $bn'$ term.

For the $\mu $ term: We have $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (nb)}{n^s}=\sum _{n=1\atop {(n,b)=1}}^\infty \frac {\mu (nb)}{n^s}=\mu (b)\sum _{n=1\atop {(n,b)=1}}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)}{n^s}$$ and now you can write this sum as a nice Euler product.

For the $\phi $ term: We have $$\phi (nb)=nb\sum _{d|nb}\frac {\mu (d)}{d}$$ so $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\phi (nb)}{n^s}=b\sum _{d,n=1\atop {d|nb}}^\infty \frac {\mu (d)}{n^{s-1}d}=b\sum _{B|d}\sum _{d=1\atop {(d,b)=B}}^\infty \frac {\mu (d)}{d}\sum _{n=1\atop {d/B|n}}^\infty \frac {1}{n^{s-1}}=\zeta (s-1)b\sum _{B|d}\sum _{d=1\atop {(d,b)=B}}^\infty \frac {\mu (d)}{d(d/B)^{s-1}}=\zeta (s-1)b\sum _{B|d}\sum _{d=1\atop {(d,b/B)=1}}^\infty \frac {\mu (dB)}{d^s}=\zeta (s-1)b\sum _{B|d}\mu (B)\sum _{d=1\atop {(d,b)=1}}^\infty \frac {\mu (d)}{d^s}$$ and this is again ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got the idea of just remaining the coprime term and do calculation after that. But I still cannot move it into the final reslut after that. Do you have some ideas about it Thank you for your inspiration and work again!

Comment: i don't think i understood your comment (not sure which is "coprime term" and which "calculation" and "result" you mean).  probably i will need a more detailed description to understand what you mean